# Can't insert content after specific division. Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js

Here is what I've got:

**ProductListView.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'views/ProductView', 'views/PaginatorView'], function($, _, Backbone, ProductView, PaginatorView) {
    var ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'productsList',
        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            // some initialization
            // that's for zurb grid                
            this.$el.addClass('twelve columns');

            for(var i = startPos; i < endPos; i++) {
                this.$el.append(new ProductView({ model: products[i] }).render().el);
            }

            this.$el.append(new PaginatorView({ model: this.model, page: this.options.page }).render().el);
            // this.$el.after(new PaginatorView({ model: this.model, page: this.options.page }).render().el);
            return this;
        }
    });
    return ProductListView;
});
```

It seems that I can't insert something after `this.$el`. The line

```
this.$el.after(new PaginatorView({ model: this.model, page: this.options.page }).render().el);
```

While it possible to append the `PaginatorView` inside the (`ProductListView`) view it seems to be impossible to insert something outside it.

Have you encountered something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$el.after` will fail because when `render()` is called, `this.$el` has not yet been inserted in the DOM (it's just a dangling div).

Backbone encourages you to wait until the HTML content of your view is ready before inserting it. This way, the browser only repaints the window once and performance is much better.

As a rule of thumb, you should only manipulate content that resides inside `this.$el` in a Backbone view.

Comment: Ok I'll try to move it to router! I was suspecting that it's dissconected from DOM. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the view element is not added to the DOM yet ("disconnected"), calling [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) on it will not change the element nor the DOM. However, it does return a collection with two elements, which you could assign to `this.$el` for appending them later. Yet I'm quite sure this is not good practise as a [`View`](http://backbonejs.org/#View) is tangled only to one single element.

Comment: That might cause some problems as `el` and `$el` wouldn't match anymore and `setElement` expects one thing as well. And you'd end up with the delegate bound to something that isn't quite `$el`. Might work but it smells bad and could break in new and interesting ways when you least expect it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "bad practise". *Breaking in interesting ways* :-)